# I want to get data from 3 different txt files and then show data randomly

Tags: php, mysql, text

Right now my system fetching data from Mysql database. Now I want to get data from 3 different txt files and then show data randomly. I've more than one line data in both text files. I want to fetch all data from both files randomly using PHP. then want to make pagination in both data sources.

can anyone help me.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Include the code.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read text file lines into an array and pick a line at random:

```
<?php
$txt1 =<<<TXT
“If you tell the truth, you don't have to remember anything.” ― Mark Twain
“Good friends, good books, and a sleepy conscience: this is the ideal life.” ― Mark Twain
“Whenever you find yourself on the side of the majority, it is time to reform (or pause and reflect).” ― Mark Twain
TXT;

$txt2 =<<<TXT
“Facts do not cease to exist because they are ignored.” ― Aldous Huxley
“Words can be like X-rays if you use them properly -- they’ll go through anything. You read and you’re pierced.” ― Aldous Huxley
“After silence, that which comes nearest to expressing the inexpressible is music.” ― Aldous Huxley,
TXT;

$lines  = explode("\n", $txt1 . $txt2);
$random = array_rand($lines);

echo $lines[$random];
```

You could instead have:

```
$txt1 = file_get_contents('/path/to/text/file');
```

And so on.

Comment: I have 30 different name in one file in other file I've 30 different reviews How can I show..?

Comment: one more question Progrock right now we are fetching data from mysql now we need to make pagination b/w mysql data and txt file how is it possible?

Comment: Hard to say, but you could `shuffle` your array or shuffle the keys, and then cache the result.  You can then `chunk` the results for pagination.  Plenty of online guides for this.